# What is the phrase for "the amount of time for paid activities"?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-requests

It might vary from company to company. When we work as a part-time employee, most companies usually pay only for the time we work. It means that we don't get paid for the break time in between.

For example, if we work from 11:00 to 17:00 and there exists 1 hour break time in between, the companies will pay only for 5 hours rather than 6 hours.

Is there a special phrase to convey the meaning of "the amount of time for paid activities"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[労働時間]{ろうどうじかん} seems to work.

The [Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%B4%E5%83%8D%E6%99%82%E9%96%93) for 労働時間 talks about 労働時間 in relation to labour laws (労働基準法), and has a section about calulating time worked (労働時間の計算・範囲).

The following is the relevant paragraph:

> **休憩時間は労働時間に含まれない。ただし、事実上の休憩時間であっても労働者が使用者の一定の指揮命令下に置かれている場合は休憩時間とは見なされず労働時間に含まれる。**休憩時間中に来客対応や電話対応をさせる場合[6]、使用者または監督者のもとで労働はしていないがいつでも労働できる待機状態である時間（手待ち時間　例：タクシーの客待ち時間。昭和22年9月13日基発17号）は、出勤を命ぜられ、一定の場所に拘束されている以上、そのような時間も労働時間に含まれる。

So basically, breaks (休憩) aren't counted as 労働時間 so long as workers are completely free on their break.

労働時間 is for normal company workers, whereas 勤務時間 is the equivalent phrase for 公務員.

> 勤務時間（きんむじかん）とは、公務員の一般職の職員が自らの職務に従事しなければならない時間のことで、民間企業の労働者に関して規定している労働基準法で言う労働時間の相当するものであり、基本的には労働基準法で定める労働時間と同様の内容となっている。([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8B%A4%E5%8B%99%E6%99%82%E9%96%93))